# Prevent `recover` from trying to print huge objects

Tags: r, debugging

`options(error = recover)` is nice for the most part, but runs into trouble if it's called when a function in the call stack has very large arguments. For example:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again" -- x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> options(error = recover)
> l = list(x = data.frame(a = rnorm(1e6), b = rnorm(1e6)))
> f = function(x) stop()
> do.call(f, l)
Error in (function (x)  :
```

R hangs there, and doesn't respond to Control-C, as it tries to stringify `l`.

How can I prevent `recover` from trying to print function arguments, or at least trying to print very large function arguments?